# Access 2010 - Creating a Report that Generates Multiple Labels from Multiple Tables

Tags: ms-access

I have a database with multiple tables.  I would like to be able to create a Report that generates multiple labels for each record in my SampleInfo table based on the information in a second table (ProjectInfo).

SampleInfo Table consists of the following:

SampleNumber (primary key)
ProjectID (linked to ProjectInfo table)
SampleID
DateCollected
TimeCollected

ProjectInfo Table has the following:
ProjectID
Series of Yes/No Fields of analyses that are checked and unchecked based on if they need to be analyzed for that particular project

I need to be able to generate a series of sample bottle labels for each record entered in the SampleInfo table that will vary based on which Yes/No fields are checked in the ProjectInfo table for that particular ProjectID.  So, there might need to be 5 labels generated for records for one ProjectID while 8 labels might need to be generated for records for a different ProjectID.

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the tests as Yes/No fields in the project table you are going to need a separate SQL to add the labels for each test.

```
INSERT INTO Samples ( ProjectId, ForTest )
SELECT ProjectInfo.ProjectId, "Test1" AS ForTest
FROM ProjectInfo
WHERE (((ProjectInfo.test1)=Yes));

INSERT INTO Samples ( ProjectId, ForTest )
SELECT ProjectInfo.ProjectId, "Test2" AS ForTest
FROM ProjectInfo
WHERE (((ProjectInfo.test2)=Yes));
```

this isn't as bad as it sounds,  you can develop them in query design window then include them all in a macro that will run all of them in one statement.

```
SampelId    ProjectId   ForTest
1           1       Test1
4           1       Test2
9           1       Test4
2           2       Test1
5           2       Test2
7           2       Test3
3           3       Test1
6           3       Test2
8           3       Test3
```

10           3       Test4